# jquery $.post failing

Tags: jquery

I got little problem here.
I have this kind of script:

```
function sendPost()
    {
            var inputedText = $('[name = "message"]').val();
            $.post('ajaxPost.php', { "text" : inputedText , "author" : session_user }).fail(alert('error!'));           
    }
```

This is HTML of button:

```
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick = "sendPost()">
```

And this is my php file:

```
<?echo $_POST['text']; ?>
```

Request is always failing and i cant find out why.

Comment: you aren't passing a callback to `.fail` - your passing the result to `alert`.

Comment: So,I have to pass callback to fail? I will check after sleep. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I made some adjustments to your code:

```
function sendPost() {
    var inputedText = $('[name="message"]').val(); // No whitespaces in selector
    $.post('ajaxPost.php', {
        "text" : inputedText,
        "author" : session_user
    }).done(function() {
        // Code to execute after successful request
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('error!');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I will check this after sleep too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for suggestions. I tried like this and it worked like a charm.I have to read documentation more precisely.

```
 $.post('ajaxPost.php',{ "text" : inputedText , "author" : session_user });
```